# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un <div> y un <section>?

Tags: html, html5

¿Cual sería la diferencia entre un `<div>` y un `<section>`?

¿Cual es la utilidad de cada uno de ellos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

¿Cómo va?

Te cuento la principal diferencia si basa en su significado **semántico**, sirve para ayudar al SEO (posicionamiento en los buscadores).

En cuanto a propiedades, funcionan casi 100% igual, ambos son elementos de bloque y no tienen ninguna diferencia. Pero sirve para hacer mucho mas optimo la diferenciación de secciones dentro de tu sitio.

Antiguamente una sección de artículos se hubiera codeado de la siguiente manera:

```html
<div class="productos">
   <div class="producto">

     <!-- Aqui iria el codigo de cada uno de tus productos -->

   </div>
</div>
```

Como se puede notar esta todo separado por div's. Si los cambiamos por la nuevas etiquetas semánticas que nos provee HTML5 quedaría algo así:

```html
  <section class="productos">
    <article class="producto">

      <!-- Aqui el codigo de tu producto -->

    </article>
  </section>
```

Realmente tiene mucho mas sentido **semántico**, y tiene exactamente las mismas propiedades que el antiguo `<div>`.

Existen otras etiquetas semánticas como `<aside>`, `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<main>`, etc...

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 3):

Complementaré con esto:

**SECTION**

De acuerdo con [la especificación](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element) un elemento `section` esta destinado para:

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.

Que podemos traducir como:

> El elemento `section` representa una sección genérica de un documento o aplicación. Un `section` en este contexto, es una agrupación temática de contenido, típicamente con un encabezado.

Te muestra como ejemplos:

- capítulos
- secciones numeradas de una tésis
- Una página web puede tener su contenido dividido en varias secciones.

**DIV**

Mientras que si del mismo [recurso](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) vemos que un `div`:

> The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its children. It can be used with the class, lang, and title attributes to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements. It can also be used in a dl element, wrapping groups of dt and dd elements.

Que se puede traducir como:

> Un elemento `div` no tiene significado especial del todo, le puedes aplicar atributos como: clases, lang y title para darle un significado semántico a los elementos agrupados en el.

Entonces como ves:

- Ambos sirven para agrupar contenido por semántica
- Uno tiene un uso específico
- Como ya te dijeron ambos son elementos [en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)
- Los `divs` son contenedores genéricos
- Te recomiendo [leer este recurso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325779/c%c3%b3mo-utilizar-correctamente-las-etiquetas-para-una-correcta-sem%c3%a1ntica-en-mi-est/325886#325886) para complementar el aspecto de usar etiquetas semánticas (*y mas que la respuesta ahi, el enlace que existe dentro de la misma para profundizar*)

> Al final de todo, deberías usar `section` de acuerdo con su definición de existir sobre `divs`.

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia se aprecia al usarlos en un móvil.

- Veras como el `div` se pone en cualquier parte del HTML
- El `section` se pone a los lados.

Comment: Si no aplicas ninguna regla CSS, pasa lo que estoy respondiendo. De hecho es la unica diferencia entre DIV y SECTION. Informate

Comment: Al igual que los dispositivos donde el espacio es reducido, el navegador opta ocultar section en vez de header o nav

Comment: mi ejemplo es sencillo, pones un div y un section, sin CSS, y ves que ocurre lo que yo digo.